# how to pickle customized vectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm having trouble pickling a vectorizer after I customize it.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pickle
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=str.split)
pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer, open('test.pkl', "wb"))
```

this results in 
"TypeError: can't pickle method_descriptor objects"

However, if I don't customize the Analyzer, it pickles fine.  Any ideas on how I can get around this problem?  I need to persist the vectorizer if I'm going to use it more widely.

By the way, I've found that using the simple string split for analyzer and pre-processing the corpus to remove non-vocabulary and stop words is essential for decent run speed.  Otherwise, most of the vectorizer run time is spent in "text.py:114(_word_ngrams)". Same goes for the HashingVectorizer

this is related to [Persisting data in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141761/persisting-data-in-sklearn) and http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/tutorial.html#model-persistence
(by the way, sklearn.externals.joblib.dump doesn't help either)

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not so much a scikit-learn problem as a general Python problem:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(str.split)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-7-7d3648c78b22>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(str.split)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle method_descriptor objects
```

The solution is to use a pickleable analyzer:

```
>>> def split(s):
...     return s.split()
... 
>>> pickle.dumps(split)
'c__main__\nsplit\np0\n.'
>>> tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=split)
>>> type(pickle.dumps(tfidf_vectorizer))
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Did this gave me an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function split at 0x000000000D5C1908>: it's not found as __main__.split

Comment: You can set vectorizer.stop_words_=None because it takes a lot of time to be serialized and also it is not needed for future use so emptying it buys some time. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html