# Vectorizer (Hashing, Count, etc.): reusing after fit_transform

Tags: scikit-learn

Suppose I have two features which are both text based; for example, say I'm trying to predict sports games, and I've got:

1) Excerpt from sports commentary (a body of text)
2) Excerpt from Internet fan predictions (also a body of text).

If I were to use a text vectorizer (say HashingVectorizer) on feature 1), with fit_transform(), would it be bad to use it again (fit_transform()) on feature 2, or should I create a new vectorizer for that? I'm just wondering whether reusing fit_transform() on multiple features with the same vectorizer might perhaps have bad side effects.

Comment: `HashingVectorizer` is entirely stateless, so it can always be reused safely. But I don't see why you don't just `fit_transform` the entire training set in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it depends on whether or not you want reproducibility of the text-to-vector conversion step.  For example, if you want to use the same classifier (or whatever) you made from the first data set, you need to reuse the vectorizer.  If you fit a new one on a different data set, it will build a different vocabulary, ie pull out different tokens, and make the vectors differently.  That might be what you want with a very different data set (if you're going to retrain).  It could be that the second data set contains new words that are critical for predictions.  Those would be missed if you reused the vectorizer.

By the way, the vectorizers can be pickled if you want to save to disk.  For an example, see: [how to pickle customized vectorizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717076/how-to-pickle-customized-vectorizer).